# The command "docker run hello-world" does not output anything

Tags: 20.04, docker

I've updated the question in response to comments below.

Here are the commands to remove, install, test, and display information about docker

Delete docker key

```
sudo apt-key list Docker
sudo apt-key del "9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88"
sudo apt-key list Docker
```

Uninstall docker

```
# sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt-get remove docker docker.io containerd runc
```

Comment out docker repository

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

sudo more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
# deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable
```

Install docker

```
sudo apt install --reinstall docker.io
```

Add group

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Docker info

```
$ docker info

Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-53-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 16
 Total Memory: 62.5GiB
 Name: cd0254nb032364
 ID: 23TM:HHHH:IE6K:ZS3W:UAQJ:6D4X:OZHT:VCTD:EHT2:YEXJ:EL3J:WLWS
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 31
  Goroutines: 49
  System Time: 2022-11-29T14:03:27.77815013-05:00
  EventsListeners: 0
 HTTP Proxy: xxx
 HTTPS Proxy: xxx
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker version

```
$ docker version

Client:
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.2
 Git commit:        20.10.12-0ubuntu2~20.04.1
 Built:             Wed Apr  6 02:14:38 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.2
  Git commit:       20.10.12-0ubuntu2~20.04.1
  Built:            Thu Feb 10 15:03:35 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.9-0ubuntu1~20.04.5
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.0-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Print date, test docker

```
john@cd0254nb032364:~$ date
Tue 29 Nov 2022 02:20:46 PM EST

john@cd0254nb032364:~$ docker run --log-driver "syslog" hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
2db29710123e: Extracting [==================================================>]  2.479kB/2.479kB
^C
```

Display syslog

```
Nov 29 14:13:46 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:13:46.399481658-05:00" level=debug msg="found match for linux/amd64 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:f54a58bc1aac5ea1a25d796ae155dc228b3f0e11d046ae276b39c4bf2f13d8c4"
Nov 29 14:17:01 cd0254nb032364 CRON[99485]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 29 14:19:33 cd0254nb032364 kernel: [708152.538463] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=301608 end=301609) time 117 us, min 1064, max 1079, scanline start 1062, end 1080
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.955928670-05:00" level=debug msg="Calling HEAD /_ping"
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.956661084-05:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.41/containers/create"
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.956842881-05:00" level=debug msg="form data: {\"AttachStderr\":true,\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":true,\"Cmd\":null,\"Domainname\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"Env\":null,\"HostConfig\":{\"AutoRemove\":false,\"Binds\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadIOps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps\":null,\"BlkioWeight\":0,\"BlkioWeightDevice\":[],\"CapAdd\":null,\"CapDrop\":null,\"Cgroup\":\"\",\"CgroupParent\":\"\",\"CgroupnsMode\":\"\",\"ConsoleSize\":[0,0],\"ContainerIDFile\":\"\",\"CpuCount\":0,\"CpuPercent\":0,\"CpuPeriod\":0,\"CpuQuota\":0,\"CpuRealtimePeriod\":0,\"CpuRealtimeRuntime\":0,\"CpuShares\":0,\"CpusetCpus\":\"\",\"CpusetMems\":\"\",\"DeviceCgroupRules\":null,\"DeviceRequests\":null,\"Devices\":[],\"Dns\":[],\"DnsOptions\":[],\"DnsSearch\":[],\"ExtraHosts\":null,\"GroupAdd\":null,\"IOMaximumBandwidth\":0,\"IOMaximumIOps\":0,\"IpcMode\":\"\",\"Isolation\":\"\",\"KernelMemory\":0,\"KernelMemoryTCP\":0,\"Links\":null,\"LogConfig\":{\"Config\":{},\"Type\":\"syslog\"},\"MaskedPaths\":null,\"Memory\":0,\"MemoryReservation\":0,\"MemorySwap\":0,\"MemorySwappiness\":-1,\"NanoCpus\":0,\"NetworkMode\":\"default\",\"OomKillDisable\":false,\"OomScoreAdj\":0,\"PidMode\":\"\",\"PidsLimit\":0,\"PortBindings\":{},\"Privileged\":false,\"PublishAllPorts\":false,\"ReadonlyPaths\":null,\"ReadonlyRootfs\":false,\"RestartPolicy\":{\"MaximumRetryCount\":0,\"Name\":\"no\"},\"SecurityOpt\":null,\"ShmSize\":0,\"UTSMode\":\"\",\"Ulimits\":null,\"UsernsMode\":\"\",\"VolumeDriver\":\"\",\"VolumesFrom\":null},\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Image\":\"hello-world\",\"Labels\":{},\"NetworkingConfig\":{\"EndpointsConfig\":{}},\"OnBuild\":null,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"Platform\":null,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"User\":\"\",\"Volumes\":{},\"WorkingDir\":\"\"}"
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.959206339-05:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.41/info"
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.968076485-05:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest"
Nov 29 14:20:52 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:52.976774280-05:00" level=debug msg="Trying to pull hello-world from https://registry-1.docker.io v2"
Nov 29 14:20:53 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:53.548021023-05:00" level=debug msg="Pulling ref from V2 registry: hello-world:latest"
Nov 29 14:20:53 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:53.548058753-05:00" level=debug msg="docker.io/library/hello-world:latest resolved to a manifestList object with 11 entries; looking for a unknown/amd64 match"
Nov 29 14:20:53 cd0254nb032364 dockerd[64419]: time="2022-11-29T14:20:53.548075219-05:00" level=debug msg="found match for linux/amd64 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:f54a58bc1aac5ea1a25d796ae155dc228b3f0e11d046ae276b39c4bf2f13d8c4"
Nov 29 14:21:30 cd0254nb032364 auditmanager: Received wakeup signal before sleep finished
```

Display docker processes in separate terminal.  Note, no processes are displayed.

```
john@cd0254nb032364:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
john@cd0254nb032364:~$
```

I don't know if this is helpful, but I tried the command

```
ohn@cd0254nb032364:~$ docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
405fecb6a2fa: Extracting [==>                                                ]  32.77kB/773kB
```

And, that command does not seem to pull the image.  If I list the images, there are none on the system, including hello-world.

```
john@cd0254nb032364:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
john@cd0254nb032364:~$
```

So, maybe the issue is my internet connection, I'm unable to pull the images down.  Is there a way to check this?  Can the images be pulled manually?

How can I debug, or correct the setup so the docker command hello-world runs?

Comment: What do the log files say? (Probably syslog?)

Comment: Well, the download for the image wasn't complete, so `ctrl+c` will have killed the process.  Have you tried rerunning again?  And then waiting a while for it to complete extraction/download?  If you don't do that it will never run.

Comment: I've reran it, and waited, but don't see any output.
$ docker run --log-driver "syslog" hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
2db29710123e: Extracting  2.479kB/2.479kB

Comment: I don't see anything in syslog related to this.  I just reran it after 13:10 and the last entry in syslog (unrelated) is at 13:08.   Do I need to add a flag to turn on log saving?

Comment: Please provide the last 30 lines from `/var/log/syslog` after running the command, and also output of `docker ps -a`.

Comment: How did you install Docker - you seem to be missing some vital components.

Comment: When you update, please confirm Docker installation with output of: `docker version`

Comment: I've added remove / install, listed syslog, and listed docker ps -a.  I think the information to solve the problem is in the syslog display, but I'm not familiar with the output.

Comment: I think you're right that somehow the problems comes from the fact that you're not able to pull the images. Are you behind a firewall that blocks anything? Do you have enough disk space? Maybe you should rephrase your entire question to focus on that you can't pull Docker images.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some vital components. Notice this:

```
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version:
```

On a working system, this should read: (the version numbers are from my Ubuntu 22.04 with Docker 20.10.21 installed from the Docker repos)

```
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 1c90a442489720eec95342e1789ee8a5e1b9536f
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
```

If you installed Docker from the Ubuntu repos, run: (I don't think many people use this option, but still..)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall docker.io
```

If you installed Docker from the Docker repos, run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Also, remember to add your user to the `docker` group.

See [more info here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll update the original question, but I still get the same error.